# Codeigniter : append record in mysqli

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, mysqli

i want to update my column data in a way that posted data gets appended at the end of the existing column data. Current data is in Json format

This is how i am updating record

```
$data=array('services', $array );
$this->db->where('id',$id)
$this->db->update('garage',$data);
```

but this updates whole record how do i append the record at the end of json

Answer (score 0):

You can select the data from the database and use PHP way to concatenate the string and run the update.

```
$d=$this->db->get_where('garage',array('id',$id))->row();
```

Now merge the you can merge the existing data with new data.

```
$new_data=$d->services.json_encode($array);

$data=array('services', $new_data );
$this->db->where('id',$id)
$this->db->update('garage',$data);
```

Hope this will fix the issue.